# Selenium chromedriver doesn't load javascript in webpage

Tags: chromium, python3, javascript, selenium

I'm running python code in a VPS with Ubuntu 18. After much trying, I was able to run the selenium Chromedriver there headfully. Now, I'm finding that the webpages sometimes loads fully, but more often than not, it opens the driver but the page only loads without the JS in it.

I don't know if I need to install something else or why is this happening

**Chromium-browser** version 84.0.4147
**chromedriver** version 84.0.4147

The VPS has a GUI included, and I did `sudo apt-get install xvfb`

The code

```
#stest.py script

url="https://www.bet365.es"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

#This for arguments above, I've tried with and without them. No difference

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
browser=webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
    
browser.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
                          "source": """
                            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
                              get: () => undefined
                            })
                          """
                        })
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', 
                            {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
    
browser.get(url)
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//div[contains(@class,"-WebConsoleModule ")]')))
```

In the bash script I type the following to run the code `xvfb-run python3 stest.py start`. After the timeout error, when I check the page source, I can see what is in there is the same as if in a regular Chrome I do Ctrl+U, which is the page without the JS loaded.

For the record, the result I get is similar to the one I'd get if I pass the `--headless` argument, which for this page is not an option as it doesn't behave properly with it

As I said, I need for this to load fully every time, not just once in a while.